# A software to organize votings

Tags: voting

I am looking for simple, easy-to-use, and if possible free software to organize votes.
What I would like it to be able to do is:

1. There should be a list of registered voters given by their email, say, which would be public to all registered voter.
2. The voters would have a time frame to vote, and their vote should be anonymous : there should be no way, for anyone, to know who voted what.
3. The result should be accessible, in real time, to all registered voter.

So do you know anything like this?

PS: this is for use in an academic context. The software would not need to be able to handle large vote -- less than 50 voters should be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) a try. The basic features are free to use. In the free account 40 participants are allowed. Maybe this participant limit is sufficient for you.

PollUnit has various types of polls. I think what you are looking for is the [voting feature](https://pollunit.com/en/voting). Here you can see two examples with different voting types:

[image]
[image]

With a premium account you can hide the voters or just hide their votes. The votes are visible for admins but not for other participants.
If you deactivate "Participants must enter their name" in the advanced step, your voters can participate anonymously (also in the free account).

With a free account you can enable and disable voting at any time. With a premium account you can automate the voting period.

All poll types are updated in realtime without the need to refresh the browser.

The only thing I still don't quite understand is the list of registered voters. You can restrict access to certain users, you can save groups (list of emails) and you could also publish the list in the description of your poll.

Disclosure: I am one of the developers.